# Formatting numbers to fixed width

Tags: bash, printf

I have this output:

```
30.1.2003
3.3.2003
25.12.2003
```

I want to make print each value except the year in two digits (might have leading values). i.e

```
30.01.2003
03.03.2003
25.12.2003
```

Comment: Where is that output coming from? It may be able to adjust it to produce the desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `printf`:

```
echo 30.1.2003 | tr . ' ' | xargs printf '%02d.%02d.%04d\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F. -v OFS="."  '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)$i=(length($i)<2?"0":"")$i}7' file
```

if your output was from some process, do :

```
yourApp|awk -F. -v OFS="."  '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)$i=(length($i)<2?"0":"")$i}7'
```